# AWS EMR PySpark UDF fails with `Failed to run command /usr/bin/virtualenv (...)`

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, amazon-emr

I have an emr cluster with emr version 6.10.0, and I'm trying to use pyspark udf within my code but it keeps failing with the same error all the time.

```
data = [("AAA",), ("BBB",), ("CCC",)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1"])
udf_f = F.udf(lambda x: str.lower(x), StringType())
df.withColumn("col_udf", udf_f(F.col("col1"))).show()
```

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o203.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 39) (ip-xxxxxx.ec2.internal executor 2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run command: /usr/bin/virtualenv -p python3 --no-pip --system-site-packages virtualenv_application_1681977466645_0017_0
```

Whole error here: https://pastebin.com/ZkAHp2JU

I have tried versions of emr below 6.10.0 and the latest it is working on is 6.5.0, but I need to get it working on the 6.10.0. Also I tried turning virtualenv off `"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "false"` and then it worked but I couldn't use sc.install_pypi_package(), it stopped working and some other stuff too.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: does everything other than UDFs work?

Comment: Yes everything else seems to be working fine except the UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to work around it by setting `spark.python.use.daemon` to `false`.

From the executor logs it seems that Spark was trying to recreate the Python virtual environment once it was already in use by the PySpark daemon.

According to comments in the Spark source code (`PythonWorkerFactory.scala`), deactivating the PySpark daemon could have a negative performance impact.

This page gives some insight into how Python workers are spawned https://books.japila.pl/pyspark-internals/PythonWorkerFactory/.

Another solution could be to deactivate the use of virtual environments `"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "false"` and instead use traditional Spark Python package management solutions (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html).